# react-testing-library testing conditional rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm having the following component:

```
const { loading } = useSelector(stateSelector)

<GoogleLoginWrapper>
   {loading && <InlineLoader />}

   <Component />
</GoogleLoginWrapper>
```

The loading data is coming from a redux store after the user logged in successfully. So when the backend finished the request. The component renders a loading indicator whenever the loading state is true. The loading state is set inside the component. I'm trying to test this component like this:

```
test('Shows loader when loading', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<GoogleLoginButton />)
    const loadingComponent = getByTestId('inlineLoader')
    expect(loadingComponent).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

But it's just not working. Basically how do we correctly test rendering conditionally using jest and react-testing-library? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Some* external stimuli usually triggers the component to do something that necessitates displaying a loading indicator, component mounted, some prop updated, a user clicked a button, etc. Can you update question with complete component code?

Comment: The loading data is coming from a redux store when the user successfully logged in. I've updated the question a bit! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, so you've some state in the redux store that holds the value that indicates the component is in a loading state, is this correct? If you can provide the entire component code we can better see how it's connected to your store and how you need to mock that value for testing? With RTL you'll create a wrapper with mock redux store provider that is used with the `render` test function as part of the passed options. Depending on how you've defined the function or connected it to redux you *may* be able to more simply mock the prop value it'd receive instead.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The loading data is called with the help of a selector like I've added above. So I would probably want to mock that loader but I'm not sure how to do that :(

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux has an example test wrapper for testing a redux connected component. If that works for you then all that is left is to create some mock test state to pass as `initialState` that has the values you need to get `loading` to be truthy.

Comment: After some trial and error, I got it working with your example! thank you very much!